# Should I dealloc @property items?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

The basic rule that I have been going by is "if I alloc, I dealloc," but is this an overly simple view?

Comment: Note that this is also [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256926/objective-c-do-you-have-to-dealloc-property-objects-before-deallocating-the-pare/3256948#3256948).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The rule is "if you invoke a method that starts with `new` or `alloc`, is called `retain`, or contains `copy`, then you must (auto)`release`".  (Easy way to remember this is the acronym: "NARC")

If you declare a `@property` as `(retain)` or `(copy)`, then you are responsible for the backed object, and you must do:

```
[myProperty release];
```

in your `dealloc` method.

Comment: Obligatory link to the complete rules: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/

Comment: @jeff the modern runtime synthesizes ivars, which means you can still use the ivar directly in the code even though you never declared it. :)

Comment: @Dave - that last comment is what threw me, i think. I started coding with that behavior and didn't think about it until recently. (ivars being synthesized) after some time away from Obj-c, I am in the habit of giving instance variables a different first letter. Thank you.

Comment: Hmmm, as far as I was aware, the synthesized ivars needs to be accessed via the "->" operator, which is unnatural for Cocoa programmers.  ie,  [self->myProperty release].

Comment: Even if it works, its documented not to.  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html.  Quote: If you are using the modern runtime and synthesizing the instance variable, however, you cannot access the instance variable directly, so you must invoke the accessor method.

Comment: @Jeff I humbly submit to the documentation. You apparently should not use synthesized ivars in `-dealloc` whether or not you *can*.

Answer (score 1):

Rule of the thumb: (Almost) never call `dealloc` directly, use `release` instead. There are some exceptions. For example, in your object's `dealloc` method you should call `[super dealloc]`.